# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in node js

Tags: json, node.js, express, request

Am using npm request to make a request to cryptonator api , but when i want to render my home page with the data coming back from the request it logs out an syntax error.

**my code**

```
router.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn,  function(req,res){
    request('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd', function(err,response,body){
        if(!err && response.statusCode == 200){
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            res.render('dash-web/home', {crypto: data})
        }
    })
})
```

**The error**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Request._callback (/home/ubuntu/workspace/bitcoin.1/main/routes/dashboard.js:61:29)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/ubuntu/workspace/bitcoin.1/main/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/bitcoin.1/main/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/bitcoin.1/main/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Comment: You're trying to parse HTML as JSON.

Comment: kk thank you for that information, what can i do to prevent the error from happening @Colin

Comment: to help you debug you could actually render the HTML that you are unexpectedly receiving - it may give you a hint as to what is happening.

Comment: Am using ejs, am really new to this, if you can help out i will be glad if you did, but i can't really figure out where the error is coming from thanks@paul

Comment: remove the line `var data = JSON.parse(body);` and replace the next line with `res.send(data);` - it should display the page you are unexpectedly receiving

Comment: I did that but the page did not open i went to my console it wrote that path must be a string @paul

Answer (score 0):

After trying this URL a number of times, it started giving me the same error as you are seeing.

What is happening is that sometimes cryptonator returns correct JSON, sometimes it returns an HTML page that has some javascript that adds some tracking data to the request and redirects it, the redirect then returns the JSON.

If you just save the following snippet as `index.js` and run it with `node index` a few times you should see the two behaviours.

```
var request = require('request');
request('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd', function (err, response, body) {
    if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
        if (response.headers["content-type"] !== "application/json")
        {
            // got redirected
            console.log(body);
        } else {
            // got proper json
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(data.ticker);
        }
    };
});
```

I have not seen this behaviour in an API before - I suppose it's some defensive measure to prevent DDOS attacks.

I would contact Cryptonator about this, it's not your code.

Comment: Ok, please keep me updated if you find anything out, thnks for also trying to sort things out. @paul

Answer (score 0):

Check your url. It may be a 404 Page Not Found. I got this same error working with Binance API. I figured out that the Binance API Docs show expired endpoints. So, instead of getting the expected JSON, I was actually getting a 404 Page Not Found website, hence the html tag. The endpoint was listed in the docs as '/fapi/v1/openOrders'. I figured out that what worked was '/api/v3/openOrders'. After making that change I got the expected result.